# Is it possible to sort an Unanswered Questions list by Date?

Tags: support, unanswered-questions

I was trying to find out if it possible to sort an Unanswered questions tab by date rather than by how many votes it has had.   I thought it would be easier to identify recent questions which are still unanswered.   E.g. when I click on the Unanswered tab off the main, it seems to sort in descending number of Votes order.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

[image: Newest sort]

Comment: -1 for lack of hand drawn circles.

Comment: Yes, thank you Kevin.   Now I see how this works.  Before I was sorting for Newest only, not within the Unanswered.   This is what I was seeking.  Thank you.